# Locate / Updatedb with archive support? (tar.gz etc.)

Tags: backup, search, search-engine

I do have many backups on my nas and my dedicated server. Some as copy within the filesystem, some archived as .zip or .tar.{bz2|gz}.

Is there any way to include the filenames within these archives in the updatedb-database?

Or is there any other tool available?

A complete desktop search engine would be too bloaty, I think.

Comment: I just chose glusterfs, but it does not like small files (1 byte files cost as much as 10000 byte files). So when importing my data, I chose to replace directories with less than 100Mo of data and more than 100inodes by their archive. Fortunately, I kept the output of tar -zcvvf when creating archives. So I will patch locate to also grep inside this output, short of an answer to your question.

Comment: nice idea. I am interested in that patch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try https://framagit.org/daajaa/find_tar that I made to answer your question. More, it explores tar files inside tar files (recursive). This is a shell script, so that you can review it yourself before use.

`updatedb_tar` outputs the list of files efficiently, you will then have to store it, after eventual conversion for direct use by slocate. Feel free to fork my project on framagit.

I made `file_sha256_tar` because that was my actual need.